# В чем ошибка? И как это убрать

Tags: python

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u040c' in position 348: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: В строке  присутствует не ascii символ.

Comment: Чтобы Вам дали более подробное решение, покажите свой код и место, где в нём возникает эта ошибка.